# Inserting php inside wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i have this code

```
<?php   $project_taxonomy_select = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ep_project_taxonomy_select', true );
        $theCatSlug = get_term_by( 'id', $project_taxonomy_select[0], 'project_filter' );
        $theCatSlug = $theCatSlug->slug;
echo $theCatSlug; ?>
```

how to put the php above in **"project_filter="** inside my query in the below php code

```
<div id="project">
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=project&posts_per_page=-1&project_filter=the php here');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <a class="all project-item <?php echo $tax ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?><?php $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'project-thumb-main', true); echo $thumb_url[0]; ?><?php } else { ?><?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>assets/img/no-project-thumb-main.jpg<?php } ?>">
        <div class="magnifier">
            <span class="text"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </div>
    </a>

<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

im using [Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress)

Please Help.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd just use simple string concatentation:

```
WP_Query('post_type=project&posts_per_page=-1&project_filter='.$theCatSlug);
```